# Cannot get code to terminate after enters correct answer

Tags: java

Write a program called PasswordChecker that does the following:
1.  prompts the user to enter a password
2.  prompts the user to renter the password
3.  checks to ensure that the two password entries are identical
4.  (for the first three attempts) Repeats steps 1 through 3 until the password is correctly entered twice.
5.  After the 3rd attempt, if the user doesn’t enter the password correctly, the program needs to display an informative message indicating user account is suspended.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class passwordChecker{


public static void main(String [] args){
String  pw1;
String pw2;
int count=0;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  do{
   System.out.println("Enter the  password:");
pw1 = keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.println("Renter the password:");
pw2 = keyboard.nextLine();
count++;
if(pw1.equals(pw2))
System.out.println("Correct");

else if(count>=3)
  System.out.println("Account is suspended");

while(pw1==pw2||count>3);
 }
}
```

Comment: You might want to paste the entire main method up to the closing brace (}), it will make this easier to explain to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be missing a closing brace (you open the `do` but don't close before `while`). Your first condition should be `count < 3` and I think you want to loop while the two `String`(s) are not equal. Something like,

```
do {
    System.out.println("Enter the  password:");
    pw1 = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Renter the password:");
    pw2 = keyboard.nextLine();
    count++;
    if (pw1.equals(pw2)) {
        System.out.println("Correct");
    } else if (count >= 3) {
        System.out.println("Account is suspended");
    }
} while (count < 3 && !pw1.equals(pw2));
```

**Edit**

The reason you don't use `==` (or `!=`) for `Object` types is that it tests reference equality only. You want to test for value equality (these `String`(s) came from different lines, so they won't compare equal by reference).

Answer (score 0):

Do it simply

```
public class PasswordChecker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pw1;
        String pw2;
        int count = 0;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the  password:");
        pw1 = keyboard.nextLine();
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Renter the password:");
            pw2 = keyboard.nextLine();
            if (pw1.equals(pw2)) {
                System.out.println("Correct");
                break;
            } else if(count == 3){
                System.out.println("Account is suspended");
                break;
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```